# Mongodb $size condition find

Tags: mongodb

Schema as following (Mongoose Styling)

```
User: 
  tickets: [
    _ticket:
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
      ref: 'Ticket'
    used:
      type: Boolean
      default: false
  ]
```

I wanna find user having at least one ticket with used key is false

**WANT**

```
{tickets: [{_ticket: ObjectId('...'), used: true}, {_ticket: ObjectId('...'), used: false}]}
```

**WITHOUT**

```
{tickets: [{_ticket: ObjectId('...'), used: true}, {_ticket: ObjectId('...'), used: true}]}
{tickets: []}
```

Does anything way without MapReduce?
Thank for your reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$elemMatch` for this as you're only checking a single field of the `tickets` array:

```
db.users.find({'tickets.used': false})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $elemMatch to find document

```
db.users.find({tickets: {$elemMatch: {used: false}}})
```

will matched object in array of document with **used === false**